# Cannot get single XElement from XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file that is structured like this:

```
<scan client="Computer1" end="9/20/2016 7:00:00 AM" start="9/20/2016 7:00:00 AM">
  <childfile>
    <name>file.ext</name>
    <lastmodified>8/31/2016</lastmodified>
    <age>19</age>
  </childfile>
  <childfile>
    <name>file2.ext</name>
    <lastmodified>9/1/2016</lastmodified>
    <age>18</age>
  </childfile>
  <childfile>
    <name>file3.ext</name>
    <lastmodified>8/19/2016</lastmodified>
    <age>31</age>
  </childfile>
  <childfile>
    <name>file4.ext</name>
    <lastmodified>8/23/2016</lastmodified>
    <age>27</age>
  </childfile>
</scan>
<scan client="Computer2" end="9/20/2016 7:00:00 AM" start="9/20/2016 7:00:00 AM">
  <childfile>
    <name>file.ext</name>
    <lastmodified>8/31/2016</lastmodified>
    <age>19</age>
  </childfile>
  <childfile>
    <name>file2.ext</name>
    <lastmodified>9/1/2016</lastmodified>
    <age>18</age>
  </childfile>
  <childfile>
    <name>file3.ext</name>
    <lastmodified>8/19/2016</lastmodified>
    <age>31</age>
  </childfile>
  <childfile>
    <name>file4.ext</name>
    <lastmodified>8/23/2016</lastmodified>
    <age>27</age>
  </childfile>
</scan>
```

I am sending a new XML element that would look like those above, it will be something like:

```
<scan client="Computer1" end="9/25/2016 7:00:00 AM" start="9/25/2016 7:00:00 AM">
  <childfile>
    <name>file.ext</name>
    <lastmodified>8/31/2016</lastmodified>
    <age>19</age>
  </childfile>
  <childfile>
    <name>file2.ext</name>
    <lastmodified>9/1/2016</lastmodified>
    <age>18</age>
  </childfile>
</scan>
```

How do I search the original XML to see if it has a scan section that has a client attribute that matches the one that is provided, and if it does match one, replace that element with the one provided. If it doesn't find a match it will need to just add that element to the existing ones.

I attempted to use:

```
originalXML.Elements("scan").SingleOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("client").Value == client)
```

where the client var is set using

```
string client = replacementXML.Attribute("client").Value;
```

it seems like this is returning null every time even though i checked the client string and it is set to "Computer1".

Any thoughts on why this is always returning null?

Comment: what happens if you try `originalXML.Root.Elements("scan")...`

Comment: Either your xml is malformed (an xml can only have a single root element), or you are not showing the entire xml structure. That makes it difficult for us to determine how to access a particular element.

Comment: @Jonesopolis if i change it to originalXML.Root.Elements....  it still returns null.

Comment: @Kevin thank you for pointing out the malformed XML. That was my issue. After i corrected it so that it had a proper(single) root element it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues...

1. Malformed XML - You must have a root element
2. You need to reference your "scan" elements off your root object

So your linq2xml will look like this...

```
var client = replacementXML.Root.Attribute("client").Value;
var match = originalXML.Root.Elements("scan")
       .SingleOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("client").Value == client);
```

OK well I guess I'm a little late.. I see your comment that you got it fixed.  :)